# Telling the HTML editor the "&" mark is not part of the code

Tags: html, signature

So I have set up rules in my signature application which is using an HTML editor at the backside, now I am trying to write a normale phrase(not coded) with a AND mark(&). But the HTML editor keeps reading this as an HTML and keeps converting it to & a m p ;

Now how do I tell the HTML that the "&" mark is not part of the HTML code?

THanks, if u need more explanation I might be able to post some print screens.

Answer (score 1):

> Now how do I tell the HTML that the "&" mark is not part of the HTML code?

You don't.  `&` is a specific symbol with a specific meaning in HTML.  It denotes the start of an entity in the code.  In particular, it's one of four which according to the spec [must always be specified as entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction#Named_character_references) because the symbols carry specific meaning in HTML code.

To represent an `&` as text in HTML, you have to use the entity definition:

```
&amp;
```

For example:

```
This &amp; That
```

renders as:

```
This & That
```

If you want an HTML editor to conform to a custom HTML spec that you define, you're going to have to build your own HTML editor.